# Is a non-awaited Task processed simultaneously (parallel)?

Tags: async-await

Until now I used to `await` my `Tasks` before continuing processing.
But now I plant to do something meaningful instead of awaiting

A normal async method where you await before continuing would be like:

```
async Task Fasync()
{
    A();
    await OtherAsync();
    B();
}
```

I am certain that B will not be called, before both `A` and `OtherAsync` have executed all their statements. I can be certain that before processing `B` OtherAsync has reached its postcondition.

I've noticed that the thread that continues after the await usually has a different thread Id. I assume this means that a different thread can continue the processing of my code after my await.

Now let's create a function that does not await:

```
async Task Gasync()
{
    K();
    Task taskF = Fasync(); // call Fasync defined above. Do not await yet
    L();
    await taskF;           // await until Fasync completed
    M();
}
```

Writing diagnostic messages showed me that the procedures are called in the following order:

```
K()
within Fasync(): A(), OtherAsync()
L()
```

So Gasync continues processing only after Fasync starts awaiting. L is not started before A returned.

Officially - as a user of Fasync - I may only rely on the pre-condition and the postcondition of Fasync. I may not assume anything about how Fasync gets to its post condition; I may not assume anything about the order in which Fasync does its work.

This gives the designer of Fasync the freedom to change his procedure without having to worry about assumptions that the caller made, as long as he meets the proper postcondition.

Just out of curiosity:
**What happens if thread X is processing L and OtherAsync completes?**

- Does thread X continue processing L, while at the same time a different thread Y continues `Fasync` by processing `M`?
- Is processing Gasync suspended until Fasync completes?
- Is processing Fasync suspended until Gasync awaits for Fasync?

Comment: `await` doesn't run anything itself. It *awaits* already executing asynchronous tasks without blocking. A Task on the other hand is just a promise that something will complete and return a value in the future. It could be a live task started with `Task.Run` that executes on a thread, or it could be an asynchronous IO Task that only becomes "alive" when the async operation completes. Or it could be a Task returned from a TaskCompletionSource

Comment: This means that this question can't be answered, because there's no information about `OtherAsync`. The rest of the code doesn't start anything in the background, it just awaits for the start started by `OtherAsync` to complete. If `OtherAsync` *doesn't* start a thread, all of this code will run on the original thread

Comment: Panagiotis: After the await I am certain that the awaited Task is completed. I know that everything in Fasync has been processed. After await I know that nothing in Fasync will be done. So if Fasync changes a variable that I plan to use, then after the await I can be certain that Fasync won't do anything with this variable anymore.

Comment: You asked about threads. Unless `OtherAsync` starts another thread, all of this code is synchronous. Moreover `the thread that continues after the await usually has a different thread Id` is only true on *web* applications. On Winforms, WPF, await returns execution to the UI thread unless `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used.

Comment: Panagiotis: no, I've seen that the thread id of the thread after an await may be different. Especially in Winforms you'll have to take care that the continuing thread has the same context

Comment: On *Winforms*? Are you *absolutely* sure? Do you have code that proves this? If you do, it means `await` is broken since 2012. The very reason for its existence is to get back to the original execution context. You wouldn't be able to modify UI controls after an `await` if what you claim is true. You'd still have to use `BeginInvoke`. *Deadlocks* happen because people start a background operation and then block the UI thread with some other work, which means `await` can't get back to the UI thread

Comment: `code that proves this` would be if a simple `async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args){ await Task.Delay(1000); textBox1.Text="Whatever";`}` threw a cross-thread exception.

Comment: Note that, as threading and async are not always deterministic, experiments like this are rarely conclusive

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few points that are worth understanding about `async`, all covered in my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html):

1. Every `async` method begins executing synchronously; it can only become asynchronous when it encounters an `await`.
2. `await` may also act synchronously if its awaitable is already complete.
3. When `await` acts asynchronously, by default it captures the current context and uses that context to resume executing the `async` method when its awaitable completes.

Those three points can answer your questions.

Specifically:

> What happens if thread X is processing L and OtherAsync completes?

As soon as `OtherAsync` completes, the continuation of `Fasync` is able to run. Whether it *actually* runs right away or not depends on the context captured by the `await` in `Fasync`. If it captured the thread pool context (or if `ConfigureAwait(false)` was used), then the continuation of `Fasync` is queued to the thread pool, where it can be run immediately by any thread pool thread, and that thread may execute `B` in parallel with `L`. However, if that `await` captured a UI thread context, then the continuation of `Fasync` is queued to the UI message processing loop, and (assuming `X` is the UI thread in this case), it will wait until `X` is free to continue executing `Fasync`.

> Does thread X continue processing L, while at the same time a different thread Y continues Fasync by processing M?

If the `Fasync` `await` captured the thread pool context, then this is possible.

> Is processing Gasync suspended until Fasync completes?

No. When there is a continuation ready to execute, it is queued. It never interrupts an executing thread. `L` has started, and `L` will run to completion before that thread is used for anything else. Once `L` has completed and `Gasync` does its `await`, *then* the `Gasync` method can be suspended.

> Is processing Fasync suspended until Gasync awaits for Fasync?

Possibly. If the `Fasync` `await` captured a UI context (and `X` is the UI thread), then the `Fasync` continuation is queued. Assuming there are `await`s "all the way up", then the `await` in `Gasync` will yield to the UI message loop, which will pull `Fasync`'s continuation from its message queue and execute it.

---

In conclusion, you mention "preconditions" and "postconditions" a few times in your question. As you work more with `async` and `await`, you'll find that `async` will gently push you in a more functional direction. It's just easier to pass data into the methods and extract results from the returned values rather than worrying about state and preconditions and postconditions. So the concepts of "precondition" and "postcondition" tend to fade in the `async` world; as the code becomes more asynchronous, side effects become minimized.

Comment: Thank you. Shortly after I posted this question I read your very informative article [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which clearly explains what you wrote above.